# Edit with textarea -> how to keep placeholder?

Tags: jquery, textarea, placeholder

First of all, what I have: a simple div, which is onClick switched to an textarea. The placeholder of the textarea is the value the div had before.

```
<div class="class" id="test">Test</div>

text = $('#test').text();
$('#test').replaceWith('<textarea onkeyup="update_textarea(this)" 
id="test"  placeholder="' + text + '" />');
```

The updateTextarea function makes the newly inserted text available as the value (means I can use the inserted text later again).

Now what Iam missing or what I want: When I click my div with the value Test, its going to be editable (because its no longer a div, it is a textarea). The problem is, the placeholder is correct, but when I click inside the textarea to insert a new text, the placeholder is deleted, the textarea is empty. How could I prevent this, keeping the placeholder as a value within the textarea?

Must be something with onFocus I think... but how to keep it.

Thanks

Comment: this is how the `placeholder` is supposed to work it is a visual prompt that is removed when the user navigates to the field. If you want an editable value in the field, then use the `value` attribute instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will helps you. Add this after `$('#test').replace...`

```
$('#test').one('focus',function(){
       $(this).text(text)
    })
```

check here http://jsfiddle.net/a8AA5/

Answer (score 1):

A placeholder attribute is designed to disappear once the user enters text into the `input`, so it's working as intended in this case. I suspect that you want to apply text to the `textarea` element instead; and, for that, I'd suggest the following:

```
$('#test').live('click',
    function(){
        $(this).replaceWith('<textarea>' + $(this).text() + '</textarea>');
    });

$('textarea').live('blur',
    function(){
        $(this).replaceWith('<div id="test" class="class">' + $(this).text() + '</div>');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8JFQG/).

References:

- [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).
- [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
    $("#test").live('click',function(){
    var text = $('#test').text();
    //var text = $('#test').html(); // use this for html tags also
        $('#test').replaceWith('<textarea id="test2">' + text + '</textarea>');
})
$("#test2").live('blur',function(){
        var text2 = $('#test2').val();
        $(this).replaceWith('<div id="test">' + text2 + '</div>');
});
    <div id="test">Test</div>
```

Check in jsFiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/VbSV5/
```